# Schengen Visa Extension (Switzerland)

Tags: schengen-visas, switzerland, visa-extensions

I'd applied for a Schengen visa for 66 days. But the Swiss embassy has approved me a visa for 40 days. Now that my non-refundable return tickets are booked, how can I extend my visa until the planned date? Is the best option to try for an extension before I fly out of India (in 5 days from today) or once I reach the Schengen states?

Comment: do you know why they did not give 66 days, the period you asked for?

Comment: Contact the consulate immediately. Do not wait even an hour, from the time that you received your passport back.

Comment: If you do get in touch with the consulate, please come back and let us know what happened.

Answer (score 4):

> Is the best option to try for an extension before I fly out of India (in 5 days from today) or once I reach the Schengen states?

It is generally not possible to extend a Schengen visa from within the Schengen area.  You therefore have three options:  You can

- try for an extension before you leave, or
- change your travel plans, or
- cancel your trip.

In my experience, changing a nonrefundable ticket may be less expensive or more expensive than buying a new ticket.  You won't find out until you ask.

This is a great example of why visa applicants are advised not to make nonrefundable purchases until after the visa has been granted.

If the consulate made a mistake, then they will probably be willing to correct it, so you should definitely get in touch with them urgently to try to resolve this before your trip is scheduled to begin.